# TensorFlow seq2seq model with low number of target_vocab_size

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am experimenting with the tensorflow [seq2seq_model.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py) model.
The target vocab size I have is around 200.

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html#sequence-to-sequence-models) the says:

> For vocabularies smaller than 512, it might be a better idea to just use a standard softmax loss.

The source-code also has the check:

```
if num_samples > 0 and num_samples < self.target_vocab_size:
```

Running the model with only 200 target output vocabulary does not invoke the if statement.

Do I need to write a "standard" softmax loss function to ensure a good training, or can I just let the model run as it comes?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing. In order to just get my fingers wet with different kinds of structures in the training data I am working in an artificial test-world with just 117 words in the (source and) target vocabulary.

I asked myself the same question and decided to not go through that hassle. My models train well even though I didn't touch the loss, thus still using the sampled_softmax_loss.

Further experiences with those small vocab sizes:
- batchsize 32 is best in my case (smaller ones make it really unstable and I run into nan-issues quickly)
- I am using AdaGrad as the optimizer and it works like magic
- I am working with the model_with_buckets (addressed through translate.py) and having size 512 with num_layers 2 produces the desired outcomes in many cases.

Comment: Thank you a lot for sharing your experience with the model! In the seq2seq_model.py did you just replaced tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer with tf.train.AdagradOptimizer? Or do I need to adapt anything else in the following for loop - for b in xrange(len(buckets)): ?

Comment: Just replace it there. The for-loop after that does not need any editing for this purpose.